# PHP preg_replace: How can I match something but not replace it?

Tags: php, regex

For example, if I wanted to preg_replace the title of a HTML element:

```
$str = preg_replace('/title=\"([^\"]+)\"/', 'foo', $str);
```

Please do not give me other solutions (non regex) for this specific example, this is merely an example. I need a solution that works for any regular expressions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to match parts with `preg_replace`, but only partially replace something else, then there are two options.
Either you just *reinsert* the matched parts (enclose in capture groups, and then use `$1` and `$3`):

```
 $str = preg_replace('/(title=")([^"]+)(")/', '$1foo$3', $str);
```

Or you use [assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
 $str = preg_replace('/(?<=title=")([^"]+)(?=")/', 'foo', $str);
```